# Oracle SQL using SET statement with a look up

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL.

I am trying to develop code to run a simple query to update column values in one table based on selection criteria and a look up on another table.

The requirement is:

```
If  CODE TABLE SERIAL NUMBER  =  SERIAL NO list table and  CODE TABLE check Code = 999 and CODE TABLE Taken up indicator = 'Y' 
THEN in CODE table 
Update
check code = 0
Taken up indicator = SPACES

SERIAL NO LIST table only holds SERIAL NO 
CODE table holds SERIAL NO; CHECK CODE ; Taken up indicator 
SOME SERIAL NO S IN CODE TABLE HAVE CHECK CODE = 999 AND Taken up indicator = Y
These need to be amended to 0 and SPACE if the SERIAL NOs MATCH
```

SQL is:

```
UPDATE
  SET CODE.CHECK_CODE = '0', CODE.TKUP_FLAG = ' '
WHERE CODE.SERIAL_NO = SERIAL_NO_LIST.SERIAL_NO
AND CODE.CHECK_CODE = '999'
AND CODE.TKUP_FLAG = 'Y'
```

I have tried many variations of this including inner joins. 
Any advice is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
update code
    set CHECK_CODE = 0,
        TKUP_FLAG = ' '
    where exists (select 1 
                  from SERIAL_NO_LIST
                  where CODE.SERIAL_NO = SERIAL_NO_LIST.SERIAL_NO
                 ) and
          code.CHECK_CODE = '999' and
          code.TKUP_FLAG = 'Y';
```

That is, do filtering in the `where` clause to get the rows that you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but according to my understand I propse the following:

```
update  CODE
set CHECK_CODE = '0', TKUP_FLAG = ' '
where CODE.CHECK_CODE = '999' 
       AND CODE.TKUP_FLAG = 'Y'
       AND CODE.SERIAL_NO IN (SELECT SERIAL_NO_LIST.SERIAL_NO FROM SERIAL_NO_LIST)
```

OTHER SOLUTION:

```
update  CODE
set CHECK_CODE = '0', TKUP_FLAG = ' '
where CODE.CHECK_CODE = '999' 
       AND CODE.TKUP_FLAG = 'Y'
       AND EXISTS  (SELECT SERIAL_NO_LIST.SERIAL_NO FROM SERIAL_NO_LIST WHERE SERIAL_NO_LIST.SERIAL_NO = CODE.SERIAL_NO )
```

you can also add condition to the sub query if needed.